# Publish message from Redis / redis stream to a micro service

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, redis-streams

I have a scenario like I would be storing details on the redis-database and this would publish messages to external API's.

**Question:**

1. Is that feasible to publish message from Redis to outside world? - All pub/sub I have seen are within **redis-cli**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- you can pub/sub to clients, but those still have to be *Redis* clients that *also know about pub/sub*.  Per your account handle, you probably need to look for a simple-but-sufficient Java library.

I wrote about a simple application I create for my own use:  a listener process fetches market data (for less than a handful of contracts) and *publishes* them to Redis from where clients (in a different process and/or on a different machine) can subscribe.  Works *great*. I do this in R because I had already written a (C++ based) client for R (around hiredis) to which we then added pub/sub.

The blog post is [here](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2022/02/23/#036_pub_sub_for_market_monitoring_with_r_and_redis), and I also wrote about Redis for market monitoring in this [short arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.08323) -- and there is a corresponding [short arXiv paper introducing Redis](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06559).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dirk.. I had the same understanding like the consumer has to be a code (written in nodejs, java, etc..) listening to the redis pub/sub. Whereas my search was something like can this be a external push to outside world.. I guess there are no way to push messages outside redis unless we subscribe to it.

Comment: Redis notifies. That is exactly what happens. It is actually quite thrilling to work with this because Redis is a neutral middle man.  You can debug by sending messages with any compliant API and receive with another.  But one needs to _publish_ so that Redis can notify all _subscribers_.